# How would I make a string get a property? C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I got this database witch would display the grade of a student based on what I would write in the code. For example:

```
id = "Robert"
classType = "mathGrades"
```

And here is my code

```
public string grades;

public string loadQuery(string id, string classType)
{
    students = jsonService.GetData(); // My Json reader gets data from my Json file
    string Class = "student." + classType; //I combine the scripts

    foreach (Student student in students)
    {
        if (student.name == id)//Check if we have a student by this name, if we do then get the grades for the class defined in "classType"  
        {
            grades = string.Join(", ", Class);//This is the part that I understand why it doesn't work, but I don't have an idea on how to replace it
        }
    }
    return grades;
}
```

This is the Student class:

```
public class Student
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<int> mathGrades { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => JsonSerializer.Serialize(this);
}
```

And this is the json file containing the data

```
 [
      {
        "name": "Test1",
        "mathGrades": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
      },
    
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "mathGrades": [ 1, 2, 3 ]
      }
]
```

I would want my output to be something like "1, 2, 3" but I just get student.mathGrades. Which I understand why, I just don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: is grades a property on students?

Comment: Please add code for `Student` class. And please add some example input and desired output.

Comment: The Student class contains a "mathGrades" and a "name" where the "mathGrades" is a list of int's and the "name" is just a simple string.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change

```
 grades = string.Join(", ", Class);
```

to

```
grades = string.Join(", ", student.mathGrades);
```

The above answer explained your mistake. String.Join expects array of values. In your example

```
string.Join(", ", "student.mathGrades");
```

returns `student.mathGrades`

Comment: I know, but I am searching for an alternative way. I want to avoid hard-coding 13 functions for 13 different classes, and just call the function with the name and the class that I want the grade from. For example loadQuery("Robert", "mathGrades"). And it would pull up the math grades for the student named Robert.

Comment: @CallMeTrebor, I don't get, where is hardcode inside your function? Why do you need 13 of them?

Comment: I would like to create a modular system where you could easily pull up grades, and in total I would have 13 classes, for now I am just experimenting with one. For example: English, German, Geography and so on. And I would like to experiment with creating a system where I don't have to write a function for every single class. So if I wanted the German grades I wouldn't need to make a function for getting the German onesm, I would just tell the 'loadQuery' function to pull it up, instead of making a 'loadQueryGerman' function.

Comment: I see, that wasn't described in your question. No need to create 13 methods like loadQueryGerman, instead you need to change Student class structure instead of List<int> mathGrades, you should have a List<Subject> subjects(each subject has name and grades). And search for a value by nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a string named Class and setting it equal to `"student.mathGrades"`.

In your loop, you are effectively saying `grades = string.Join(", ", "student.mathGrades")`

Since `"student.mathGrades"` is just a single string, there is no joining and it's just returned.

If you want to have grades return a list of grades you need to pull that list from somewhere. It would help to know what your student object looks like.